# How can i call multiple actions in a single form being generated by struts iterator

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a list of ticket objects which i am displaying in my jsp using strut tags. The list works fine, the rows are rendering properly. What i need to do is two provide two functionality for each row - **Details** and **update**

A part of my JSP...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function details()
{
    document.forms['ticketForm'].action="viewTicket.do";
    document.forms['ticketForm'].submit();
}

</script>

                       <s:iterator value="ticketList" var="tl">
                        <tr>
                        <!-- The problem form which should call 2 actions -->
                        <s:form id="ticketForm" action="updateTicket" theme="simple">
                        <!-- This hidden field is required in both actions -->
                        <s:hidden name="ticketId" value="%{#tl.id}" />
                        <td valign="top" width="5%"><s:property value="id" /></td>
                        <td valign="top"><s:property value="requesterName" /></td>
                        <td valign="top"><s:property value="guestName" /></td>
                        <input type="button" value="Details" onClick="Javascript:details()" />
                        <s:submit value="Update" />
                          </td>
                          </s:form>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="10"><script language="JavaScript">Rule();</script></td>
                        </tr>
                        </s:iterator>
```

Now the problems:
1) UpdateTicket action works fine but not the **viewTicket action**(the one being rendered through javascript). It always calls the details of ticket in row 2 no matter which row i click. If i use s:submit instead of  for the second action, the form's default action, i.e. updateTicket is being called all the time. How can i fix this.

2) The update ticket in **row 1** never works. It always reloads the same page and do some strange stuff. However the update ticket action is working fine in all other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign different id to each form and then run the application. Make the following changes in your code also on both JSP and Javascript

**JSP Changes**

```
 <s:iterator value="ticketList" var="tl" status="stat">
                        <tr>
                        <!-- The problem form which should call 2 actions -->
                        <s:form id="ticketForm%{#stat.index}" action="updateTicket" theme="simple">
                        <!-- This hidden field is required in both actions -->
                        <s:hidden name="ticketId" value="%{#tl.id}" />
                        <td valign="top" width="5%"><s:property value="id" /></td>
                        <td valign="top"><s:property value="requesterName" /></td>
                        <td valign="top"><s:property value="guestName" /></td>
                        <input type="button" value="Details" onClick="Javascript:details(<s:property value='%{#stat.index}' />)" />
                        <s:submit value="Update" />
                          </td>
                          </s:form>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="10"><script language="JavaScript">Rule();</script></td>
                        </tr>
                        </s:iterator>
```

**Javascript Changes**

```
function details(index)
{
    document.forms['ticketForm'+index].action="viewTicket.do";
    document.forms['ticketForm'+index].submit();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That worked!! Thank you very much. But my other problem still remains - None of the action is working in the first row. None....

Comment: when u submit the form from the first row, is there any exception coming on the server console?

Comment: No exception. No nothing. The client side code seems fine too. Maybe its something internal.

Comment: when you submit what is the url that comes up in the browser

Answer (score 0):

From where are you reading the ticket id which you are supposed to display details of.

I guess this is the one, but remember you are using an iterator, and the id is a constant. So it can hold only one value, which will be the last one of the iterator. Try looking at the html generate source from browser to see what value this field holds.

Workaround:
Instead go for [struts tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/using-tags.html) (for both update and view):

**s:url**

and

**s:param**

Sample,

```
<s:url action="urlTagAction.action" >
    <s:param name="id">123</s:param>
</s:url>
```